# Выравнивание блоков по высоте в Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Нужно сделать выравнивание этих блоков по высоте в Bootstrap 3, какой способ будет самый оптимальный и не сломает адаптивную верcтку?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать [так](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/wbkevw1u/7/)

Имея структуру типа:

```
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

CSS будет такой:

```
.col-container {
   display: table; 
   width: 100%; 
}

.col {
   display: table-cell; 
   width: 50%;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .col { 
       display: block;
       width: 100%;
    }
}
```